Linux in a reboot cycle after installation
I tried installing Linux Mint (the latest version) on an old laptop I have, a Samsung NP300V4A. The installation, at first, went well. Then I had to restart the laptop. It restarted, removed the USB and pressed enter. Then, a bunch of SQUASHFS ERROR started appearing. Turned it off and on again and it just gets on a reboot cycle. Every 5 seconds it tries to boot, then restarts, again and again. I tried reinstalling Linux Mint again with the USB, and the menu says that I have Linux Mint installed (in that part of the menu that says if you want to install linux along windows, if you want to remove windows or do something else). I tried changing the order of boot (put it back to system default) and it didn't work. It works normally when the USB is connected.

It first seems that the harddisk has problems, use the 'Disks' program in the 'live' (usb) session to check it.
I made a search, and there is one post about the same problem in the site bbs.archlinux.org

I don't know if this is what you mean or is related, but I tried using another USB with the same Linux Mint and the problem persists

It seems related to the hardware of the PC.
As you write   "... on an old laptop.. ", the problem is probably there.
But, seeing the specs (Intel Core i3-2310M @ 2.10GHz, 4Gb) the CPU coeff is 1220, and with 4Gb, personnaly i will no spend too much time trying installing.
Try a search with
<Samsung NP300V4A  "linux"  "mint"  install>
to check if there is more information to find.
Or try to install another distro.
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/3448vs3485vs2275vs892vs756/Intel-i5-9300H-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-3700X-vs-Intel-i7-4790K-vs-Intel-i7-3612QM-vs-Intel-i3-2310M

No, not "tried using another USB", use a live session on USB to check the hard disk with the 'disk' command
